# Expressing constraints in scipy's linprog

Tags: python, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

Let's say we have a cloud of n points, m dimensional: x1(x1m1, x1m2...), x2, x3...
Now let's add an aditional point p(pm1, pm2...)

Point P needs to fulfill these 3 conditions:

1. P = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 ... Basically a dot product of [x1,x2,x3,x4...] and [a1,a2,a3,a4...]
2. Each a is a scalar positive coefficient, ak > 0
3. Sum of a must be equal or lower (since we are in floating point, lower works) than 1, a1 + a2 + a3... <= 1 (if =1, it means we are on the boundary)

The aim is not to know the coefficients themselves, but if the problem is feasible or possible to solve.

From what I understand, this is 1 equality and two inequality constraints, how would I input these in scipy's linprog?

P.S.: I'll leave this image in case it helps. Basically a convex hull membership problem. 2nd opinions would be very welcome, I have been working some time on this and found solutions online but to me they are not intuitive

[image: My expectations in the 2D case]

Comment: What are typical values of m and n? Are "point p" and "point P" the same thing? What is k?

Comment: Does it have to be scipy linprog? That's somewhat limited. If you can cut down to glpk, you might be able to evaluate feasibility without paying attention to the actual solution, e.g. with `glp_get_prim_stat` and family

Comment: @Reinderien It does not matter as it should be general and i'm going to test easy m=2, n<10 first, then move to 3d cause those are the only ones I can visualize, but in my particular case n=3 million, m=23. It's very expensive. Point p and P are the same, just a typo. k is an index, it represents all elements a1, a2, a3...


To your other comment, I would love to try that if it is faster. I read somewhere the feasibility problem has the same computational cost as the problem itself though

Comment: @Reinderien I found several packages; glpk, pyglpk, scikit-glpk... Do you recommend one of them?

Comment: I've used swiglpk with success, because it's simple and direct; but others will work